# How to insert an integer value into a textbox using stored procedure calculations?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a stored procedure for calculating the pf of an employee as given below:

```
USE [test]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DA] 
AS
BEGIN
SELECT e.emp_id,
e.name,
p.salary,
p.category,
p.salary * 0.12 as da
from emp as e,
payroll as p where
e.emp_id = p.emp_id
END
```

I have to display the result i.e values of DA in a textbox in C# when we select different values for salary from a drop down list. Please help me with the C# code.

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepeted if it works for you

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 :

Read data in dataReader

step 2 :

Set value in textbox from the reader.

Step 3 :

In dropdwon change vent write following code....

Eample :

```
          // Open connection to the database
                string ConnectionString = "server=myserver;uid=sa;"+
                    "pwd=manager; database=northwind";
                con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                con.Open();

                // Set up a command with the given query and associate
                // this with the current connection.
                string CommandText = "DA";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                storedProcCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;



                // Execute the query
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while(rdr.Read())
                {
                    mytextbox.Text =rdr["da"].ToString() ;                
                 }
```